# Scene with two UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Just started to explore Storyboards in Xcode development.
I have first scene with two UIButtons. Both button's segues points at the same scene but with two different scenarios. Am I understood right that for implement this I need to set segue identifier in IB (e.g seg1,seg2) and then in .m implement only one method like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"seg1"]) {
 // first scenario
  } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"seg2"]) {
 // second scenario
  }
}
```

If not, how to implement this behavior?
Thanks, Alex.

Comment: In first place, don't try to compare strings using `==` (C basics, lesson 2.)

Comment: Thanks! Does -isEqualTo the right way comparing in this case?

Comment: No, NSString doesn't recognize isEqualTo:. You should use isEqualToString:

Comment: Rewrited code in question, thank you! What about main question?

Comment: @Alexey either `isEqualToString:` or `isEqual:` should work

Comment: Thanks, but is it a right way to implement what am I asking about?

Comment: Yep, so you'd then set the appropriate property for your destination controller inside those if statements to get the desired behavior. You're on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are technically correct — the best kind of correct